# Relational DB (SQL) - How to associate 2 non-related tables with a 3rd table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, erd

I got 2 tables:

**TABLE 1**

```
CREATE TABLE product(
    p_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    p_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

**TABLE 2**

```
CREATE TABLE retailer(
    r_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    r_name varchar(60) NOT NULL
);
```

I would like to store images for the products and for the retailers. 1-1 relationship.
I don't want to have **product_images** table and **retailer_images** table.
Product and Retailer may have the same ids.
I want 1 **images** table to keep all the images on it and have a relation with it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a composite key with Id and ImageType columns

Comment: Yes, two different tables can refer the same third table. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Don't make things too complex, simply create the images table, and add image id columns to retailers and products tables - both fk's.

Comment: @jarlh yes, that's a good option. But is there a cleaner way? Is it possible to do that without changing the original schemas? I'd love to see an implementation for Stu's approach or something similar

Comment: @jarlh actually that will be enough since the relationship here is 1 to 1. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra column to both tables, eg:

```
ALTER TABLE product
ADD (
    p_image varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
   
);
```

do same for the retailer table to store the image_name/image_id and use join to query from both tables creating a 1-on-1 relationship.

Check the documentation example here: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-joins/

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to store the images on those tables. I want to gather all the images on a single table that will contain only images. I prefer not to mix the images with the textual data that I store on each entity.

Comment: which flavour of sql are you using?